# What Does The Following Lambda Function Mean?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I am trying to understand the code behind this solution. This function takes a list of file name and sort by extension (filename.extension is the format) and puts full file name with extension only but not a name (.config for example) first. I am having a hard time understanding the 3 arguments within the lambda function. What does each one of them do?

```
def sort_by_ext(files):
return sorted(files,key=lambda x:(bool(i:=x.rfind('.')),x[i+1:],x[:i]))
```

Comment: Edited: bool operator not appropriately used.

Comment: `code` def sort_by_ext(files):
    return sorted(files,key=lambda x:((x.rfind('.')>0),x[x.rfind('.')+1:],x[:x.rfind('.')]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down:

---

```
bool(i := x.rfind('.'))
```

This will assign to `i` the last position that a period is found in the string `x`. It will also return `True` if it has a filename (basically, if the last period is not at the beginning), and `False` if it doesn't (basically, if the last period *is* at the beginning).

---

```
x[i+1:]
```

This will return the file extension (basically, everything after the last period).

---

```
x[:i]
```

This will return the file name without the file extension (basically, everything before the last period).

---

To wrap it all up, the code sorts by the following (in the order it appears below):

1. Whether there is a filename
2. The file extension
3. The filename minus the file extension

Comment: also @ Seth Python Tutor which runs on Python 3.6 seems to think the above code I posted is an syntax error. Which version of python are you using (just for my learning and I know the code is correct)?

Comment: Actually *test* that first thing on a string without a period. You *don't* get `False`.

Comment: @superbrain thanks for pointing that out! What is the point of `bool(i := x.rfind('.'))` though?

Comment: @Larasing I am running Python 3.8

Comment: @SethPeace Well, for what strings *does* that result in `False`?

Comment: @superbrain strings that are just a file extension!

Comment: @SethPeace Indeed. As also mentioned in the question, with the example ".config".

Comment: @superb rain thank you for pointing this out. I have revised the code based on Seth's explanation + your point on how the bool operator is not appropriately used.

Comment: @Larasing What do you mean the bool operator is not appropriately used?

Comment: see comment for my edits... not elegant but perhaps fixes the bool operator bit